# Trying to work out how to call an array from a seperate array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am very new to flash but I am learning fairly quickly. I understand about arrays etc but I have promised my boys i would try to make a Yu-Gi-Oh game for them. I know there are some already out but I want to make a few changes to the original. The problem I can not get past is the array names. Most card games you use 2 types, `rank` and `suit`. With Yu-Gi-Oh you use about 10 such as `name`, `type`, `attack`, `defense` etc.

With all of this in mind I searched through Google and found 2 ways to do this, an XML file which I have not any idea how to use, but the most promising seemed to be to make a card definition `class` which got used by the card class that stored just the card name.

In essence the card def class for say a card named dragon hold all of its values while the card class hold all the different card names. This way I could deal out say 6 card names from the card class and each card would be able to call the value from that cards def. Of course knowing what to do and knowing how to program is 2 separate things. Can anyone tell me of a way this could work please and bear in mind I have been trying to learn flash for a couple of weeks only.

Edit, i'm not allowed to answer my own question for another 5 hrs so will just edit this for now in reply to the answer below.

Thanks for the reply Floran. I think i can work out the comparators easily enough. The hard part was all the data needed to be held. As an example ["Alexandrite Dragon1", "monster", "light", 4, "dragon", 2000, 100] are the stats of the Alexandrite dragon. I was thinking of having that as say the array of the alexandrite dragon and doing 1 of these for each card all held in a card def class.

After that i would want a card array which would hold each of these so that array may be [alexandrite dragon, ganbara knight] etc so when i dealt the cards if someone drew the alex dragon from the card array [0] then i thought maybe to get that cards atk maybe something like card [0] [5] would get it or even card[0[5]]. Im obviously not sure if this could work and after spending 3 days searching google etc i figured it may be easier to just ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you are tackling at the moment.

1. structure
2. rules

Thinking about a structure and rules may be done separately, but since you have to apply rules to the cards and this determines a lot of the games basic idea, i try to compress it a bit.

A card should, as already mention, all the data necessary which represents a game card. This means it holds a label to give it a meaningful name which can be displayed, some properties like type, attack or defense or more as well.

```
package net.icodeapps.examples {
  public class Card {
    public var label:String,
               type:String,
               attack:int,
               defense:int;
  }
}
```

This is the most basic way to create a card. But in order to interact with the data held by the cards, you need some sort of comparator: which card is more powerful.

```
package net.icodeapps.examples {
  public class CardComparator {
     public function attackCompare(card1:Card, card2:Card):Card {
       if (card1.attack < card2.attack) return -1;
       if (card1.attack > card2.attack) return 1;
       return 0;
     }

     public function defenseCompare(card1:Card, card2:Card):Card {
       if (card1.defense < card2.defense) return -1;
       if (card1.defense > card2.defense) return 1;
       return 0;
     }
  }
}
```

This way you can determine the stronger card in attack or defense. If you need a more complex way to determine values:

```
package net.icodeapps.examples {
  public class CardComparator {
    public function compare(card1:Card, card2:Card):Card {
      const diff1:int = card1.attack - card2.defense,
            diff2:int = card2.attack - card1.defense;
      if (diff1 < diff2) return -1;
      if (diff1 > diff2) return 1;
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

But you see, the pattern is the same. Isolate state from "behaviour" (although it is just a small context illustrated). If such attributes like type play a role, enhance the comparator. If you need to enhance class properties, you would want to add methods to the Card class.

Now, you can create Cards, and compare them. The next thing would be a collection, which can be an Array or Vector. But don't use these to store properties. This will only bring you in hell's kitchen.

But i guess this is a starter.